# What is the "next stage" in the Area 51 site proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51

If you go to the Area 51 proposal *[Internet Marketing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37889/internet-marketing)*, it says it's in the "Definition" state and it needs blah.. blah to go to the next stage. Well, what ***is*** the next stage?

This should be a link to a page which explains what the stages are or show some kind of a timeline/progress state on this page.

Practice some ["Don't Make Me Think"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758).

Comment: to the people who voted to close it because it's off topics, How is it off topic?

Comment: A few months ago, the team shifted responsibility for questions about Area 51 from MSO to A51's own "Discussion Zone."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Area51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), the phase after Definition is:

> **Commit!** When a proposal enters the "Commitment" phase, we will present a petition for the site's creation. Interested users are asked to digitally "sign" the proposal with their full name to help assure that site will have an active community in those critical early days. While your full name is never shown, you may add an optional comment which is displayed alongside your username in the list of committers. To ensure that commitment is taken seriously, you may only commit to three sites at any one time.
>
> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site. If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta, or until six months after the beta began.

(And the phase after that, in case you're wondering, is *Beta*). However, is it really necessary to explain what the next phase is right there? If a proposal is still sitting in Definition, it still needs to get the followers and questions it needs to move into Commitment, so it doesn't really matter at that point what's next, until it gets past the current thing blocking it.

Comment: Yes it matters to some people. It's like filling an online form where it tells you which page you are from the total or where you are in a check out process. You still have to finish the current stage to go to the next but it's always good to get a feeling of how much work is still ahead to be done.